# Log normalized data?

Tags: regression

Is it a good rule of thumb that when you are running a regression model that if your data is not normal or has a lot of noise to log normalize that data 
Or is it better to run a quadratic model on the data?  From Wikipedia it states, "if the random variable X is log-normally distributed, then Y = ln(X) has a normal distribution." Which makes sense but I am not sure on how to clean up non-normal data sets.

Comment: Both are terrible rules of thumb!  Taking logs is no universal cure and quadratic relationships often yield poor fits.  Your question about dealing with datasets you find unusual is a good one to ask, but it's far too broad to be dealt with in a single thread on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a suspected lognormal variable you can overlay a lognormal distribution and look at lognormal q-q plots to get a better understanding of the lognormal fit.

As you likely know, the normality assumption in linear regression is on the residuals. Thus if residual assumptions appear met you don't necessarily need to normalize independent variables. However, it would be presumed to help the fit, so can be explored. Thus natural log transforming the variable would be acceptable. Though you will need to note that the coefficient interpretation will change as wells when you transform data. You can then interpret it on the percentage scale or back-transform the coefficient.

Given the variable is lognormal or approximately lognormal the above transformation should be fine over using polynomials. If the variable doesn't quite seem lognormal, exploring the use of polynomial may be another option to improve fit.